# Integral of an exponent of an exponent

Tags: calculus, integration, exponentiation

For a homework problem, I have to integrate this:

$$\int{4^{(4+x)^x}}dx$$

How would I go around to starting this question? I don't know how to evaluate this, and I've tried to use u-subs and integration by parts, but to no avail. Could anyone lead me in the right direction?

Comment: Right click on the formula below to see how to format an exponent of an exponent:$$4^{(4+x)^x}$$The curly brackets are essential!

Comment: What kind of answer are you looking for?  Have you posted the full problem?

Comment: I'm not really looking for an answer, but rather a hint or some kind of lead to help me solve it. The whole problem is for me to integrate the function.

Comment: **ALERT!! No result found.**

Comment: Is this a problem of definite or indefinite integration? Neither seem likely to give a nice result for this integrand, but the former is more tractable than the latter.

Comment: If this is indeed a homework problem, you've probably copied it incorrectly. Either that, or your teacher likes pranks. :-)

Comment: Lol, Lucian, I'm confused about the problem, but I'll contact my teacher.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is almost certainly no closed form solution.  Even the much simpler integral $\int x^x$ cannot be expressed in terms of elementary functions.

You could do various numerical approximations to find bounds, or maybe write down a power series expansion.  But that's as far as you can really go here.

Comment: Thanks for the confirmation, I'm going to contact my teacher about the problem.